# VirtualBox: Windows 7 says it's not genuine

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, virtualbox, product-key, windows-genuine-advantage

I've set up a Windows 7 guest machine under Windows 7 using oracle virtualbox 4.2.
This Windows Guest has its own product key which corresponds to the boxed set I
purchased for the sole purpose of running it in virtualbox. A few months ago
I backed up my Windows 7 virtual box virtual disk image on an external hard drive.
Now that the Windows 7 started to malfunction, I deleted it, and copied it back
from my external hard drive.

However now it's telling me that the version of windows is not genuine.
How can it be. There is nothing else using the same product key, unless
someone hacked into my backup folders and stole the protuct key from there
and used it on a machine of their own.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## To start the Product Activation Wizard, follow these steps:

1. Click Start Button[image]
2. Right-click **Computer**.
3. Select **Properties**.
4. At the bottom of the window, click **Activate Windows now**.

In the Product Activation Wizard, follow these steps:

1. Click **Use the automated phone system to activate**

[image]
 2. Click the drop-down menu, select the location that is nearest to you, and then click **Next**.
[image]
 3. The Product Activation Center telephone number is displayed under **Step 1**.
[image]

For more information about how to activate Windows 7, go to the following Windows Online website:
[Activate Windows 7 on this computer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/activate-windows-7-on-this-computer)

[Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950929)

### Please Read:

> Just an added note, sometimes the phone system will tell you that you
>   have installed this key the maximum number of times. It will then ask
>   you how many PCs are running that copy, and you can say "zero", which
>   will allow you to proceed with activation.

Comment: Just an added note, sometimes the phone system will tell you that you have installed this key the maximum number of times. It will then ask you how many PCs are running that copy, and you can say "zero", which will allow you to proceed with activation.

Comment: Thanks. Still not sure why I was getting the error but I called and entered the numbers in groups A through H and my windows 7 copy got reactivated.

Comment: this is such an annoying pos. good people have to pay the price while I'm sure whoever this is intended for has another hack.

Comment: @Timmerz - What?  I have never had a problem even after activating the same license three different computers by accident.  That is what the phone system is for.